# Looping multiple items but only loop unique ones

Tags: c#, loops, umbraco

I currently have a loop that loops different tags which are dynamically loaded from Umbraco.

This is the result of my loop:
[image]

Code of the loop:

```
@{ var Artikelen = Model.Content.Children.Where(NieuwsTemplate => NieuwsTemplate.DocumentTypeAlias == "newsDetail"); }
@foreach (var tag in @MainTag.Children){
    foreach (var NewsArticleTags in Artikelen){
        var DifferentTags = NewsArticleTags.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("themeTags");
        foreach(var TagNames in DifferentTags){
            if(@TagNames.Name == @tag.Name){
                <center><a class="ajaxFilter" data-catId="@tag.Id">@tag.Name</a></center>
            }
        }   
    }    
}
```

I decided to add a bool so it only loops 1 of each. I obviously messed up because it only loops the very first tag. Where am I suppose to put the bool so it loops each tag only once? 1 "Gamification" 1 "VR / AR" and 1 "Leren Programmeren"

Here is the code with the bool added:

```
@{ var Artikelen = Model.Content.Children.Where(NieuwsTemplate => NieuwsTemplate.DocumentTypeAlias == "newsDetail"); 
bool ShowTag = false;}

@foreach (var tag in @MainTag.Children){
    foreach (var NewsArticleTags in Artikelen){
        var DifferentTags = NewsArticleTags.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("themeTags");
        foreach(var TagNames in DifferentTags){
            if(@TagNames.Name == @tag.Name && !ShowTag){
                <center><a class="ajaxFilter" data-catId="@tag.Id">@tag.Name</a></center>
                ShowTag = true;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

which displays this:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this issue?

EDIT for @DZL

```
@{ var Artikelen = Model.Content.Children.Where(NieuwsTemplate => NieuwsTemplate.DocumentTypeAlias == "newsDetail"); 
bool ShowTag = false;}

@foreach (var tag in @MainTag.Children){
    foreach (var NewsArticleTags in Artikelen){
        @*var DifferentTags = NewsArticleTags.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("themeTags");*@
        var distinctTags = Artikelen.SelectMany(a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("themeTags")).Select(DifferentTag => DifferentTag.Name).Distinct();
        foreach(var TagNames in distinctTags){
            if(TagNames == @tag.Name)
            {
                <center><a class="ajaxFilter" data-catId="@tag.Id">@tag.Name</a></center>
                ShowTag = true;
            }
        }           
    }        
}
```

**FINAL CODE THAT FIXED IT**

```
@{
var Artikelen = Model.Content
    .Children
    .Where(c => c.DocumentTypeAlias == "newsDetail");

    var distinctTags = Artikelen
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("themeTags"))
    .GroupBy(node => node.Name)
    .Select(group => group.First());


}

@foreach (var DifferentTags in MainTag.Children){
foreach (var tag in distinctTags)
    {
        if(DifferentTags.Name == tag.Name)
        {
        <center>
            <a class="ajaxFilter" data-catId="@tag.Id">@tag.Name</a>
        </center>
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: Can you use `Distinct`?

Comment: I've removed Javascript tag - it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: Can you share your model you're attempting to iterate?

Comment: I do not think I can use distinct in Umbraco. What I'm trying to loop are different tags which are connected to news articles. Each article has their own tag connected to it. I only want to display the tags that are actually being used so I only display the tag if the tag's name matches the tag connected to the news article. Does that help?

Comment: @DavidG The reason why I added the javascript tag is because what I build could probably be done in javascript as well. I'm using razor script which can use javascript, C# and HTML through each other.

Comment: @Mik3NL Distinct is a Linq feature, and Umbraco supports the .Net version that includes Linq.  So it should be supported.

Comment: @Greg yes sorry excuse me. I'm not used to razor at all. I just looked at Umbraco's cheatsheet.

Comment: @Fildor yes I can use distinct

Comment: @Mik3NL Glad you solved it, I thought Umbraco's tutorials had something similar as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
@{
    var Artikelen = Model.Content
        .Children
        .Where(c => c.DocumentTypeAlias == "newsDetail");

    var distinctTags = Artikelen
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("themeTags"))
        .GroupBy(node => node.Name)
        .Select(group => group.First());
}

@foreach (var tag in distinctTags)
{
    <center>
        <a class="ajaxFilter" data-catId="@tag.Id">@tag.Name</a>
    </center>
}
```

Comment: Hey, it seems like a good idea. How do I go about implementing this though? It does distinct the tags but it keeps looping the tags more than once. I only want to show 1 tag only. I displayed my code in the main post.

Comment: @Mik3NL - you got it wrong in your code, here is the full implementation - replace everything with this one and it should work.

Comment: I made a small adjustment to show the correct tag under the correct maintag. Man you definitely helped me out here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What about saving the last tag ?

```
@{ var Artikelen = Model.Content.Children.Where(NieuwsTemplate => 
NieuwsTemplate.DocumentTypeAlias == "newsDetail"); 
var lastTag = null;}

@foreach (var tag in @MainTag.Children)
{
    foreach (var NewsArticleTags in Artikelen)
    {
        var DifferentTags = NewsArticleTags.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("themeTags");
        foreach(var TagNames in DifferentTags)
        {
            if(@TagNames.Name == @tag.Name && @TagNames.Name != @lastTag.Name)
            {
                <center><a class="ajaxFilter" data-catId="@tag.Id">@tag.Name</a></center>
                @lastTag.Name = @TagNames.Name
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I'm sorry i don't how to use those tag's property but i think you can get what i'm trying to explain